# Voice chat app that does not reveal my IP or other real-world details to other users

Tags: android, desktop-client, privacy, communication

I am looking for a way to voice chat without giving other users my info (IP address and other computer mumbo jumbo)

Without being able to be tracked and not paying for one of those VPN things. Sorry I'm not very computer literate. Mainly looking for an Android app, but I guess a Windows app will do if needed.

Do "private" apps like Signal hide this info?

Comment: Related and privacy-oriented as well: [Skype alternative for Linux with counterpart for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11714/185) Difference: it's asking explicitly for P2P, so just the opposite from yours. I don't want a "3rd party service" monitoring all my conversations (that could happen in your case) – which for me outweights the issue of a communication partner seeing my IP (which I could avoid via proxy/VPN use in a case where it's necessary). Yeah, I know: we're both a bit paranoid :)

Answer (score 3):

[**Discord**](https://discordapp.com/) is a great voice/text chat tool which has IP protection.

The Android version can be found here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.discord

But its also available on the web, Windows, OS X, Linux and iOS here:
https://discordapp.com/download

Your IP is hidden because unlike many programs (e.g. Skype), it's not p2p (peer to peer) which just means that it doesn't go from me to you, It goes from me to the Discord servers to you.

```
P2P: Me → You

Non P2P: Me → Discord Server → You
```

The Discord server has a different IP and since they receive the packets (data) from there the IP that they see is not yours.

Though do remember not to click links from people you don't trust because they can get your IP if you open external links.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, with Discord people can't find out where I live unless I disclose it? Is there another app that would allow me to click on links or does make me vulnerable because they might be linking to something they own?

Comment: @freaky_leaky_faucet That is correct they cannot get info unless you disclose it. The thing about link is yes they could own it or it could be a service online which captures your IP and then forwards you to a different site. The only way to safely click on links without disclosing your IP would be using a proxy or VPN.